# Question regarding derivation from Hydraulics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, fluid-dynamics

**Context: Fundamental properties (behavior) of infinitesimal disturbances to flow.**
The coordinate system is placed on the bottom of a channel. Basic linearized equations per unit width are denoted as:

$$\frac{\partial h'}{\partial t}+{{h}_{o}}\frac{\partial U'}{\partial x}+{{U}_{o}}\frac{\partial h'}{\partial x}=0 , \tag{1}$$

$$\begin{align}
  &\frac{\partial {U}'}{\partial t}+{{U}_{o}}\frac{\partial {U}'}{\partial x}+g\frac{\partial {h}'}{\partial x} \\
 &\quad = g\left\{ \sin \theta -{{n}^{2}}\left( {{U}_{o}}^{2}+2{{U}_{o}}{U}' \right)\left( \frac{1}{{{h}_{o}}^{{4}/{3}\;}}-\frac{4}{3}\frac{{{h}'}}{{{h}_{o}}^{{7}/{3}\;}} \right) \right\} \\ 
 \tag{2.1}\\ 
&\quad = g\left\{ \sin \theta -\frac{{{n}^{2}}{{U}_{o}}^{2}}{{{h}_{o}}^{{4}/{3}\;}}-{{n}^{2}}\frac{2{{U}_{o}}U'}{{{h}_{o}}^{{4}/{3}\;}}+{{n}^{2}}\frac{4}{3}{{U}_{o}}^{2}\frac{h'}{{{h}_{o}}^{{7}/{3}\;}} \right\} \tag{2.2}
\end{align} $$

and

$$\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{h}'}{\partial {{t}^{2}}}+2{{U}_{o}}\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{h}'}{\partial x\partial t}+\left( {{U}_{o}}^{2}-g{{h}_{o}} \right)\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{h}'}{\partial {{x}^{2}}}+\frac{2g{{S}_{o}}}{{{U}_{o}}}\left( \frac{\partial {h}'}{\partial t}+\frac{5}{3}{{U}_{o}}\frac{\partial {h}'}{\partial x} \right)=0 \tag{3}$$

where

- $U$: cross sectional averaged velocity
- $\theta$ and ${S}_{o}$: channel slope
- $n$: roughness coefficient
- ${U}_{o}$: uniform flow velocity at ${h}_{o}$
- ${h}_{o}$: depth evaluated by Manning's formula $\sin \theta =\frac{{{n}^{2}}{{U}_{o}}^{2}}{{{h}_{o}}^{4/3}}$

Eq. (3) is obtained from (1) and (2.2) but I am not sure how. I would be grateful if someone could help.

Comment: First thing that I observe: the variable $s_o$ appears in the third equation but not anywhere else. Do you know what it is?

Comment: @EditPiAf Thank you for the edit. It am a new comer to the site. I have added some contexts please let me know if more is required.

Comment: @MattiP. ${S}_{o}$ is the slope of the Channel. Please let me know if any other information is required. Thank you.

Comment: Is it from a book (which one?), from lecture notes? These [channel flow equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-channel_flow) are linearized [shallow water equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_water_equations) (Saint-Venant). Seems that information is missing to get the result. What is the link between the slope $S_o$ and the angle $\theta$? Note that the vocabulary for the parameters found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manning_formula) is different...